# Processing Files using ParallelForeach. Is this the best approach

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Just some advice
I have 100.000+ xml file to process and move to another system.

The concept is pretty simple I have a loop like:

```
    public void ProcessFiles()
    {
        IEnumerable<FileInfo> orderedFiles = GetFilesOrdered();

        foreach (FileInfo file in orderedFiles)
        {
            ProcessFile(file);
        }
    }
```

I have been reading about Task Parallel library but not that confident.
Not that very glued up on threading.
It seems that TPL wraps lots for me.

To put it simply is it just a case of using parallel.Foreach?

any sample or suggestions

Comment: Hi, For the thread safety, Better to make sure any of these file can not be accessed concurrently.

Comment: @Joe.wang Thanks do you mean adding a lock? if not could you provide me with a snippet?thanks for your time

Comment: What is the `index` variable for? You don't seem to use it.

Comment: @Bridge removed index sorry should not be there

Comment: @user231465 Don't be sorry, just wondered that's all!

Comment: What does `ProcessFile` do? Is it CPU-bound? If not, then trying to parallelize it may actually make it slower, not faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it might be as simple as replacing `foreach` with `Parallel.ForEach`.

You have to remember that multiple threads would now be executing `ProcessFile` concurrently.

So, if you are writing to any shared state in that method, you will have to use synchronization constructs to protect it.

If you're new to multi-threading, there's a great introductory ebook you should read here: [`Albahari`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Comment: One more thought: Adding parallelism here only makes sense if the IO currently isn't the bottle-neck

Comment: @NicholasButler how do you avoid race conditions with parallel library then? do you use a lock

Comment: @user231465 That's a huge topic. I suggest you read Joe Albahari's ebook. You will need to understand everything in it if you're going to write concurrent code correctly.

Comment: @NicholasButler thanks.I understand.Basically we still have to deal with locks,deadlocks etc with TPL then.

Comment: @user231465 Yes, you still have to deal with the concurrency. PLINQ and the TPL make it easier to create and control threads and tasks, but you still have to make sure your code can handle the concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is helpful to you. Simple snippet to demo how to move the file in parallel.

```
        List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();
        files.Add(new FileInfo("F:\\1.xml"));
        files.Add(new FileInfo("F:\\2.xml"));
        files.Add(new FileInfo("F:\\3.xml"));



        Parallel.ForEach(files, f =>
        {
            f.MoveTo("d:\\test\\" + f.Name); 
        });
```